# Change Ubuntu One account associated with Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core, kiosk

I've set up a kiosk device with Ubuntu Core, but now I want to hand it off and have someone else administer it. I don't want their ssh key in my account and I don't want my ssh key associated with their account. How can I go about changing the Ubuntu One account associated with the device?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just logging out?

Comment: How do you log out of an Ubuntu Core instance that's been associated with an Ubuntu One account?